# Get index of row select after push new UIVIew

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsindexpath

I have a problem: when i select row and get index of row then new `UIView` is called. When `UIView` disappear, current index of row is `null ( 0x000000)`. This is my code:

I declare rowupdate variable:

```
NSInteger rowupdate;
```

`didSelectRowAtIndexPath():` I get index of row and push `UIView`:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    DetailView *detailAlert;
    rowupdate = indexPath.row;
     detailAlert = [[DetailView alloc] init];
            [self.view addSubview:detailAlert];
            [detailAlert show];
            [detailAlert release];

           }
}
```

And then `UIView` disappear, I called:

```
[resevFileName replaceObjectAtIndex:rowupdate withObject:memotext];
```

But in console print rowupdate is null (0x000000) and resevFileName array is null (0x00000) too . Do anybody have suggestion? Thank you

Comment: Why you are using pointer type NSInteger *rowUpdate????????

Comment: @Sachin: Thanks, i edit without "*"but UIView disappear, rowupdate and array is still null

Comment: "resevFileName" how and where you are creating it, which data it does contain ?

Comment: resevFileName is that retained properly?

Comment: I create resevFileName array when viewDidLoad. and when new UIView appear, i input some text after set this text to resevFileName array.But when new UIView disappear,resevFileName array is NULL @suraj

Comment: I declare NSMutableArray *resevFileName; in .m file

Comment: declare your array in viewDidLoad

Comment: where are your putting this NSInteger rowupdate;?

Comment: @Rajneesh071: i put NSInteger rowupdate; as global variable in .m file

Comment: where in .m? is it in viewDidLoad? or in @interface?

Comment: what is your "detailAlert" doing and when you are adding this view, see whether viewDidUnload of your tableController class getting called or not? if it does that may cause some problem.

Comment: Then answer your own question..

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your variable as:

```
NSInteger rowupdate;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: does it really make any sense?

Comment: Actually I was suggesting same thing.. i.e. remove '*'.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work when you declare the row as :

```
int rowUpdate
```

in .h file .

But also try with :

```
static  int row;
```

in .m file .

Comment: Thats strenge , are you using same view controller ?

Comment: I tried  static int rowupdate; in ViewDidLoad, it can be use in other function

Comment: try to declare it just below @implementation

Comment: I declare it just below @implementation, it error : Type name does not allow storage class to be specified

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct in understanding your answer than I think you need the current selected index in your detail view right?

If this is the situation than you should just need to declare a propery in your detail view like:

```
@property(nonatomic,readwrite) NSInteger rowupdate;
```

and In your didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
   DetailView *detailAlert=[[DetailView alloc] init];
    detailAlert.rowupdate = indexPath.row;
            [self.view addSubview:detailAlert];
            [detailAlert show];
            [detailAlert release];

           }
}
```

Comment: Is DetailView a nib file?

Comment: I think you're alloc init should be before assigning the value to the property!! Check my answer now...

Comment: DetailVIew is custom view class

Comment: Than just alloc init it before calling detailAlert.rowupdate = indexPath.row;

Answer (score -1):

`NSInteger *rowupdate;`should be `NSInteger rowupdate;` with out ' ***** '

`NSInteger` is a primitive data type.

Comment: Thanks, i edit without "*"but UIView disappear, rowupdate and array is still null